# Spectrophotometric determination of copper concentration

Tags: spectrophotometry

### Context:

A typical lab experiment involves the addition of ammonia in excess to solutions of copper(II) to produce a complex ion whose absorbance at roughly 610 nm varies by the concentration of copper in solution.

### Question:

Why is it ***less practical*** to simply test the ***aqueous solution*** of $Cu^{2+}$ rather than complexing it first with ammonia?

### Thoughts:

My thoughts on this begin with the Beer-Lambert law: $$A =\epsilon lc$$

If the molar absorptivity of the ammonia complex in the visible spectrum around 600 nm is greater than that of the aqueous complex, [1] then small changes in concentration of copper can be differentiated by large changes in absorbance. This increases the sensitivity of spectrophotometric methods of determining copper(II) concentrations.

### References

[1] http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/demos/main_pages/18.8.html

Comment: If you have data that indicate the absorptivity is higher, you answer is correct.  But you might be missing the higher solubilization as a small component to this as well.